# set session variable to user_id when user logs in

Tags: php, mysql, session

I'm setting up a login/logout and I'm trying to send the users id number to other pages in the website so that I can manipulate the database when I want.

I use a query to match email/password and log in user(n.b. this is not the full code and not the problem, I'm matching emails and passwords)

```
$find= mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$ema' and password="$pw");
```

Then I fetch an array and start a session which I then check on pages further on in the website.

```
if(mysql_num_rows($find) == 1){
  $row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_BOTH);
  $id= $row ['id'];
  session_start();
  $_SESSION['Login']= $id;
// Redirect - I use JS to send users to next page
}
else {
  echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
  echo 'alert("Invalid Username or Password");';
  echo 'history.back();';
  echo '</script>';
}
mysql_close($link);
```

On other pages I have code that checks for the session and redirects users if they aren't logged in. Here's that code:

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['Register'])){
  if(!isset($_SESSION['Login'])){
    header("location:../notLoggedIn.php");
 }
}
$get_id = $_SESSION['Register'];
$get_id = $_SESSION['Login'];
?>
```

Then, when I check what's in the id variable passed from the login page with this:

```
$profile = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM profiles WHERE id= $id");
    var_export($id);
```

I get a null value. What's going wrong?

Comment: put session_start(); on header.

Comment: first check if you are getting record from your db. See it comes inside `mysql_num_rows($find)` .

Comment: @MahaDev I'm getting the record. I checked and the full array is there.

Comment: Not in the least bit constructive. I may not have worded my question the best but that comment doesn't help one bit.

Comment: I just checked what's in the `$id= $row ['id'];` variable and I got the correct result for the id number. So that should be getting passed to the session variable. So the problem is with the code at the top of protected pages. I set it to check if a session has been set when a user registers or if a user logs in, then I set the session variable to a regular variable so that I can use in the code of any page, but I have two variables. How can I make it one?

Answer (score 0):

You must check if session is not started then use `session_start();`

```
if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {//php >5.4
    session_start();
}
```

and use `$_SESSION['Login']` instead of `$id`

```
$profile = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM profiles WHERE id=".$_SESSION['Login']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Multiple mistakes i have seen.

1)First revise your query :

```
$find= mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$ema' and password='$pw');
```

2) Secondly start session on the top of file.

3) `mysqli_close($link);` instead of `mysql_close($link);`

4) In the Last check if the session is properly set.

```
if(isset($_SESSION['Login'])) {
$get_id = $_SESSION['Login'];
$profile = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM profiles WHERE id= $id");
var_export($id);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi Please note these points

1) Start `session_start` on the top of page (before any `echo` or `white space`).

2) I don't see your `$_SESSION['Register']`. Have you set it

3) You are passing `session variable` not simple `variable` so use this

```
$profile = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM profiles WHERE id =  $_SESSION['Login']");
    var_export( $_SESSION['Login']);
```

As `$id` will be `null` here always